# Gnome 3 uninstall failed?

Tags: 12.10, unity, gnome, xorg

Oke now i really messed up my system. I have tried to uninstall gnome 3. 
I have followed this [guide](http://supportlife.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/tutorial-how-to-removeuninstall-gnome-3-in-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal/).

But now my system do not anything at all. When I boot it stops when it needs to load the GUI. I thought keep calm there must be an easy solution for this. I opened a tty and did this commands:

```
sudo apt-get install dist-upgrade 
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel //get errors about dm :/
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell //same
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop //get message that distibution is unstable
sudo apt-get install unity
start lightdm // Don't work :(
```

Is there any way I can recover my system?

Comment: try `# apt-get purge gnome-shell`

Comment: Don't work: error gnome-shell not installed.

Comment: "sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a" I have founded this command. Can I run it safe without loosing my data.

Comment: Yes, that command will not break your system in theory. That will reconfigure every package in your OS, so it will take a long time 1-2 hours.

It means: `dpkg` - Debian's package manager, `-reconfigure` - reconfigure, `-p` - Priority of configuration - `high` - A high priority, and `-a` - configure all packages.

Comment: Failed to, I just reinstalled ubuntu again. :( alle my configuration gone :'(.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this case i would say just reinstall ubuntu.

1. Boot using live CD
2. Open terminal and do `sudo nautilus`
3. Copy your Home directory to an external device
4. Remove your ubuntu parions using gparted
5. Start installation
6. Copy over your files / or just the files you need ;).
7. Start configurate your system again (Have fun with that).